# Max number of consecutive keywords in Java

Tags: java, max, keyword

Does anyone know what is the max number of consecutive keywords in Java?

The longest I've come up to is 6:

```
    private static final native synchronized int function();
```

Thanks :)

Comment: StackOverflow FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to troll, but I was just wondering about this, and I couldn't find any definite answer anywhere else.